# Finding basis of a span in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$S=\left\{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4})\in \mathbb{R}^{4} : x_{1}=x_{2},\ x_{3}^{2}+x_{4}^{2}=1\right\}.$$

I have found that one vector will be $(1\ 1\ 0\ 0)$ because $x_1=x_2$ but since $x_{3}=\pm \sqrt{1-x_{4}^{2}}$ I am not sure how the find other vectors that will be basis for $[S]$.

Comment: Who says $S$ is a vector (sub)space?

Comment: The span of $S$ is. The title is clear about that and I suppose $[S]$ is supposed to denote the span of $S$ here.

Comment: Do you mean a basis for the span of $S$?

Comment: Span of S exactly. S is not a subspace

Comment: Thats why I put  a span in the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $S\subseteq\mathbb R^4$ is a subset of the $3$-dimensional subspace $U\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ given by $x_1=x_2$ and hence for the linear span $\langle S\rangle$ we also have $\langle S\rangle\subseteq U$.

Now observe that the three vectors
$$
v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\  
v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\  
v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
are elements of $S$ and linearly independent. Hence $\langle S\rangle$ is at least of dimension $3$, but as a subspace of $U$ it is also at most of dimension $3$.

Thus, we must have $\langle S\rangle = U$ and the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ form a basis.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Algebrah Note that the vector $(1,1,0,0)$ you suggested is not an element of $S$ but is an element of the span $\langle S\rangle$, since $(1,1,0,0) = (1,1,1,0) - (0,0,1,0)$ and both those summands are in $S$.

Comment: 1 1 0 0 is  not in S but is in [S] can I still use it as vector of basis for [S] since 1 1 0 0 is in [S]?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you need to argue why it is in the span.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort